# Multithreading in Sqlite

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite

I am using System.data.sqlite for connecting to Sqlite Database, as per the [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), users can enable multithreading by using **SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX** flag as part of connection string. But I couldn't find any key in the connection string which accepts flag. Is it enabled by default? if not how can I do this?

Comment: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/56.aspx

Comment: In other words, multi-threaded use seems to be the default.

Comment: multi-threade *use* is the default but not multi-threaded mode.  serialized is the default which of course allows for multi-threaded use in a safe way (serializing calls)

Comment: My C# code is threadsafe, or I am ensuring thread safety from my C# code, but I want to use Multithreaded mode of SQLite in runtime, using connection string. How can I do that?

Comment: It doesn't appear you can control that - look at the pubic SqlLiteConnectionBuilder properties - none allow the threading mode.  I don't see anything that suggests you get more than the default - serialized mode which allows for muti-threaded *use* but not multi-threaded mode.  Might be wrong but I don't see anything publically exposed ...

Comment: bryanmac : It seems like that only, but I found one DefaultIsolationLevel property, I am not sure will it work or not.

Comment: Hi @Anuraj ! I am exactly at the point you were and struggling to figure out how to set Threading mode in System.data.sqlite ? I want to use the Serialized mode in my C#  .NET application. Can you please let me know you have did this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threading mode is determined by compile time, startup or runtime options.  More details here:

http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

The docs say serialized is the default which means you're fine to use from multiple threads - it will guard you.  If you want more parallelism, you can use multi-threaded mode.

If you use it in multi-threaded mode, make sure that calls are synchronized for a given connection.  If you want parallel work, use multiple connections and guard the connection.

The API itself hints at this by taking the db object (connection) as an argument to many functions that you call sequentially.  For example, look at these functions that you call to get an error:

```
int sqlite3_errcode(sqlite3 *db); 
const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
```

Comment: I want to make it multithreaded in runtime. how can I specify it in .Net provider?

Comment: My only hesitation is that's a 2005 post.  You may want to look at the source code and see what it's doing.  If it's multi-threaded by default, then you need to create multiple connection objects and ensure each of the connection objects are serialized.

Comment: @Anuraj: I just grepped the source. It seems that the threading mode is never specified explicitly, and there is no way to configure it at run-time through the managed wrappers. The default is still set to serialized.