# Opening database connection with the SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX flag in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

After reading the [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) I wanted to make sure that by run-time the connection to the database is in the correct mode.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

I'm using the Sqlite JDBC driver. How can I add the SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX flag?

Comment: Please check this link it asked before at C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801361/multithreading-in-sqlite

Comment: The conclusion is that the Sqlite database runs in serialized mode by default and I can't change it. :-(

Answer (score 3):

After I had some doubts why in C it looks so easy and in Java it should not possible, here probably the solution:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.READWRITE);
config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.CREATE);
config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.NOMUTEX);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( //
              "jdbc:sqlite::memory:", //
              config.toProperties() //
);
```